# How to disable the draggable image feature from product add/edit in admin area magento 2

Tags: magento2, gallery-image, ui

I am trying to disable the draggable feature so I can keep the position as it is. Also trying to implement the position input into `img-dialog-tmpl` but it not saving the values.

1. disabled the draggable feature
2. add position input above image and dialog template.

https://prnt.sc/ho71mw

https://prnt.sc/ho72ad

I am trying to all thing on `"gallery.phtml".`

```
/vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/adminhtml/templates/helper/gallery.phtml
```

Just trying into core base file, once implemented, I will extend it on our theme.